# The derivative of an unknown function is additive?

Tags: calculus

Assume that we have a function:
$$
y=f\left(x,z(x)\right)
$$e take the derivative of this function with respect to $x,$ we
get:
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\times\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
$$
My question is this: while $f\left(.\right)$ is an unknown function,
the derivative on the RHS with respect to $x$ enters additively (i.e. the derivative with respect to $x$ is added to that with z.) Why is this
additive, and no say, multiplicative? Will this hold for any function
$f?$ Is this a theorem/rule?

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain words "with respect to $x$ features additively" - what you mean?

Comment: Summand for derivative with respect to second variable is added to derivative with respect to first variable by chain rule for multi variable function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the chain rule. Because everything depends on $x$, $y$ is as mooth function $\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$, so the Jacobian of $y$ is a real number. We can write $y$ as the composition of two function $F:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^2$, given by $x\mapsto (x,z(x))$, and $G:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $(x,z)\mapsto f(x,z)$. Then, the Jacobian of $y$ is given by:

$$D(G\circ F)=DG\circ D_xF$$
So, we see that $DG$ is just the gradient $[\partial f/\partial x,\partial f/\partial z]$, while:
$$DF=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
\partial z/\partial x
\end{pmatrix}$$
multiplying the two matrices gives:
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\cdot\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}
\end{align}